# How to add to a list without getting NULLREFERENCEEXCEPTION?

Tags: c#, list, class

I've been trying to add to a list of lists adding information from an sql db. The error I get when adding new info to a list is this:

"An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in StatusScope.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

How would I solve this error?

MapLogic.cs

```
public static List<MapModel.ClientInfo> GetClientsData()
    {
        SqlConnection Connection = site.Models.Shared.DBConnection.GetConnection();
        SqlDataReader Reader = null;
        SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand("SELECT DocInfo.DocID, DocInfo.DocName, DocInfo.DocPic, DocInfo.PatientAcceptance, ClientInfo.ClientName, ClientInfo.AddressLocal, ClientInfo.AddressBroad, ClientInfo.Phone, ClientInfo.Lat, ClientInfo.Long, ClientInfo.ClientID FROM DocInfo INNER JOIN ClientInfo ON DocInfo.ClientID = ClientInfo.ClientID;", Connection);
        Reader = Command.ExecuteReader();

        var ClientsData = new List<MapModel.ClientInfo> { };
        int IDCounter = 0;
        bool FirstRun = false;

        while (Reader.Read())
        {
            if (!FirstRun)
            {
                ClientsData.Add(new MapModel.ClientInfo { Id = IDCounter, ClientID = Reader["ClientID"].ToString(), ClientName = Reader["ClientName"].ToString(), DocPic = Reader["DocPic"].ToString(), PatientAcceptance = Reader["PatientAcceptance"].ToString(), AddressLocal = Reader["AddressLocal"].ToString(), AddressBroad = Reader["AddressLocal"].ToString(), Phone = Reader["Phone"].ToString(), latitude = Reader["Lat"].ToString(), longitude = Reader["Long"].ToString(), DocNames = { } });
                FirstRun = true;
            }
            else
            {
                for (var x = 0; x < ClientsData.Count; x++)
                {
                    if (ClientsData[x].ClientID == Reader["ClientID"].ToString())
                    {
                        ClientsData[x].DocNames.Add("123"); //error occurs here
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ClientsData.Add(new MapModel.ClientInfo { Id = IDCounter, ClientID = Reader["ClientID"].ToString(), ClientName = Reader["ClientName"].ToString(), DocPic = Reader["DocPic"].ToString(), PatientAcceptance = Reader["PatientAcceptance"].ToString(), AddressLocal = Reader["AddressLocal"].ToString(), AddressBroad = Reader["AddressLocal"].ToString(), Phone = Reader["Phone"].ToString(), latitude = Reader["Lat"].ToString(), longitude = Reader["Long"].ToString() });
                    }
                }
            }




            IDCounter++;
        }

        Connection.Close();
        return ClientsData;
    }
```

MapModel.cs

```
public class ClientInfo
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string ClientID { get; set; }
            public string ClientName  { get; set; }

            public List<string> DocNames { get; set; }

            public string DocPic { get; set; }

            public string PatientAcceptance { get; set; }
            public string AddressLocal { get; set; }
            public string AddressBroad { get; set; }
            public string Phone { get; set; }
            public string latitude { get; set; }
            public string longitude { get; set; }


        }
```

Comment: *"DocNames = { }"* this line is suspicious.

Comment: change  public List<string> DocNames { get; set; } to  public List<string> ? DocNames { get; set; }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you ever set `DocNames`  to anything?  If not, it will be null.

In the constructor for `ClientInfo` you should have

```
DocNames = new List<string>();
```

to initialize an empty list.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't it the case of testing whether `ClientsData[x].DocNames` is null before adding? You could change your code to

```
if(ClientsData[x].DocNames == null) {
    ClientsData[x].DocNames = new List<string>();
}

ClientsData[x].DocNames.Add("123");
```

so that it always works.

Comment: What about using `new List<string>()`?

Answer (score 2):

In both lines where you add a new MapModel.ClientInfo to your ClientsData list, you need to initialize DocNames to a new List() otherwise whenever you try to access DocNames, it's always null. So, in both places you need to do the following:

```
ClientsData.Add(new MapModel.ClientInfo                 
{ 
  Id = IDCounter,                       
  //.
  //. removing code just to make my answer shorter
  //.
  DocNames = new List<string>()
});
```